# Как получить количество постов по выбранным таксонамиям?

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть фильтр постов. Самих фильтров около 20 шт (160 значений).
Хочу добавить вывод количества доступных постов для каждого значения фильтра.
Примерно так
[image: пример]
И чтобы значения изменялись в зависимости от выбранных значений фильтров.
Как я понимаю в реалтайме это сделать нельзя, так как все будет очень медленно работать.
Но и заранее просчитывать у меня не получается, так как чтобы просчитать посты для каждого значения фильтра, при пересечении двух фильтров нужно выполнить 25000 запросов.
Как это делают на подобных сайтах?

Comment: Это у вас термины или метаполя?

Comment: @Krya И то и то

Comment: передаете гет-параметры и потом обрабатываете их и изменяете на pre_get_posts $wp_query.